# How to prompt client id and client secret in swagger

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-editor

How to allow user to input client id and client secret in swagger? This is what i have for security definition but It prompts accesstoken which is obtained through client_id and client secret, but I have not been able to make it ask client id and client secret?

```
securityDefinitions:
  api_auth :
  type: oauth2
  authorizationUrl: 'https://randomapi/aa/token.oauth2'
  flow: implicit
  scopes:
```

Answer (score 4):

I also had the same issue. What worked for me was to define flow as application :

```
flow: application
```

Comment: This is true for OpenApi 2.0. In OpenApi 3.0 it is called `client_credentials`

https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/main/versions/3.0.3.md#oauth-flows-object